# Django REST Framework Depth Only For Specified Fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have a **Django REST Framework** Serializer. Now I added a serializer for my Blog Posts, but I want the Serializer depth only for a specified field. Until now I get this:

```
{
  "results": [
      {
          "postid": 1,
          "title": "Test Title",
          "slug": "test-title",
          "description": "Test Description",
          "tag": {
              "tagid": 1,
              "tagname": "school"
          },
          "views": 15,
          "release_date": "2021-05-25T17:15:22.223311Z",
          "user": {
              "userid": 1,
              "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$216000$drVQlm6CdO+g90ygM3gXFUHBb+ctaKDA=",
              "username": "user1",
              "email": "testemail@gmail.com",
              "posts": 0,
              "date_joined": "2021-05-25T17:13:29.865119Z",
              "last_login": "2021-05-25T17:14:12.808671Z",
              "is_admin": true,
              "is_active": true,
              "is_staff": true,
              "is_superuser": true
          },
          "city": "New York",
          "country": {
              "countryid": 1,
              "continent": "america",
              "countryname": "usa",
              "currency": "$",
              "symbol": "US"
          }
      },
      ...
    ]
}
```

This is my serializer:

```py
class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ["postid", "title", "description", "slug", "tag", "views", "user", "release_date", "city", "country"]
        depth = 1
```

But the problem is, I only want the **depth** for tag and country, not for user :/ Like this:

```
{
  "results": [
      {
          "postid": 1,
          "title": "Test Title",
          "slug": "test-title",
          "description": "Test Description",
          "tag": {
              "tagid": 1,
              "tagname": "school"
          },
          "views": 15,
          "release_date": "2021-05-25T17:15:22.223311Z",
          "user": 1,
          "city": "New York",
          "country": {
              "countryid": 1,
              "continent": "america",
              "countryname": "usa",
              "currency": "$",
              "symbol": "US"
          }
      },
      ...
    ]
}
```

Did you ever had the same problem? Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you also have serializers for tag and country:

```
class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = TagSerializer(read_only=True)
    country = CountrySerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ["postid", "title", "description", "slug", "tag", "views", "user", "release_date", "city", "country"]
```

Comment: Thank you! Works fine